# (GRA) Overkill * Challenge: What qualifies as an "Animal" for this challenge?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have the Gun Runners DLC for Fallout New Vegas and I am trying to complete one of the challenges that comes with the DLC, '(GRA) Overkill *':

> Kill (20) Animals with any Fat Man or Fat Mines.

The problem is, I don't know what "Animals" means...  I've tried shooting my Fat Man at a pack of Geckos.  When I checked my challenge I didn't have any progress towards challenge completion (0/20).  So then I tried to shoot a mini-nuke from my Fat Man at a pack of Bighorners.  When I checked the challenge progress it still said 0/20.

What are considered as "Animals" for this challenge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Fallout Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Overkill):

> Mutated animals do not count, only regular animals such as ravens, coyotes, and all types of dog, including NCR, Legion, and Fiend dogs.